# How can I stop my ball in unity firing multiple times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following the Learn To Code By Making Games (Block breaker game section) course from Udemy and I'm on about lecture 80 and I just realised that I can click my mouse more than once, and it will start my ball moving again, while in game and while the ball is already moving. I hope you know what I'm trying to say. So basically I want the ball to fire when the mouse is clicked, and then not have any effect after that. But also keep into consideration, the game has lives, so once one life is lost, so the game should basically reset so the player can continue with the game (like atari breakout does). Anyway, any ideas on how I could make it only? (Below is my code for the ball)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
    private Paddle paddle;
    private Vector3 paddleToBallVector;
    private bool hasStarted = false;
    private int speed;

    //private Vector3 changeSpeed;

    private Vector3 resume;
    public Collider2D pauseCollider;

    void Start () {
        paddle = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Paddle>();
        paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position - paddle.transform.position;
    }

    void Update () {
        if(!hasStarted) {
            this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;
        }
    }

    public void startGame () {
        //print ("Mouse Has Been Clicked\n Launching Ball");
        hasStarted = true;
        this.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (0f, 200f);
    }
}
```

Comment: you might need to wrap game start with a if(!hasStarted) aswell just like in update

Comment: Until you show where `startGame()` is being ran, i don't think anyone can help you

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Thanks! That got it!